# not able to log in to a website using post request in python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to enter my username , password and login into the website.I am a begineer to this and am trying this for the first time.I dont know if I have to include any other data here.

The sample website that I am trying is: http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login.I am passing my credentials and checking if the contents of the welcome page appears after successfully logging in by printing page.content.But it displays the content of access denied(this appears when you enter the wrong credentials).I dont know where I am wrong here.

```
import requests
with HTMLSession() as c:
    url='http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
    usr='admin'
    pwd='12345'
    c.get(url)
    login_data=dict(username=usr,password=pwd)
    c.post(url,data=login_data)
    page=c.get('http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=welcome')
    print(page.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this but it seems like you used the wrong names for the username and password parameters in the request. A quick inspection of the request sent by the site shows this:

[image: request]

As you can see, in the form data the username is sent as `usr` and the password is sent as `pwd`. However, when you built the dict for the login data, you used `login_data=dict(username=usr,password=pwd)`, which constructs a dict of `{"username": usr, "password": pwd}`, which does not match the requirements of the actual request. What you want instead is `dict(usr=usr,pwd=pwd)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the `<form>` tag in page source. Or you can check the Network tab for post request for the name value of each field. The correct field names are **usr** and **pwd**.

[image: Network Tab of Browser]

So basically change this line of code:

```
login_data=dict(username=usr,password=pwd)
```

to

```
login_data=dict(usr=usr,pwd=pwd)
```